# Saving and reading variable size list from TFRecord

Tags: tensorflow

What would be the best way to store sparse vector to TFRecord? My sparse vector only contains ones and zeros so I decided I'll just save indexes where 'ones' are located like this:

```py
example = tf.train.Example(
        features=tf.train.Features(
            feature={
                'label': self._int64_feature(label),
                'features' : self._int64_feature_list(values)
            }
        )
    )
```

Here, `values` is list containing indexes of 'ones'. This `values` array sometimes contains hundreds of elements, sometimes none at all. After that I simply save the serialized example to tfrecord. Later, I'm reading tfrecord like this:

```py
features = tf.parse_single_example(
    serialized_example,
    features={
        # We know the length of both fields. If not the
        # tf.VarLenFeature could be used
        'label': tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.int64),
        'features': tf.VarLenFeature(dtype=tf.int64)
    }
)

label = features['label']
values = features['features']
```

This doesn't work because `values` array is recognized as a sparse array and I don't get data that I have saved. What is the best way to store sparse tensor in tfrecords and how to read it?

Comment: Does anyone have an answer ? :)

Comment: Please take a look at my answer below. Does that answer the question for you?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just serializing the locations of 1s you should be able to get out your correct sparse tensor with a little bit of trickery:

The parsed sparse tensor `features['features']` will look something like this:

`features['features'].indices: [[batch_id, position]...]`

Where `position` is a useless enumeration.

but you really want `feature['features']` to look like `[[batch_id, one_position], ...]`

Where `one_position` is the actual value you specified in your sparse tensor.

So:

```
indices = features['features'].indices
indices = tf.transpose(indices) 
# Now looks like [[batch_id, batch_id, ...], [position, position, ...]]
indices = tf.stack([indices[0], features['features'].values])
# Now looks like [[batch_id, batch_id, ...], [one_position, one_position, ...]]
indices = tf.transpose(indices)
# Now looks like [[batch_id, one_position], [batch_id, one_position], ...]]
features['features'] = tf.SparseTensor(
   indices=indices,
   values=tf.ones(shape=tf.shape(indices)[:1])
   dense_shape=1 + tf.reduce_max(indices, axis=[0])
)
```

Voila! `features['features']` now represents a matrix that is your batch of sparse vectors concatenated.

NOTE: that if you want to treat this as a dense tensor you'll have to do `tf.sparse_to_dense` AND the dense tensor will have shape `[None, None]` (which makes it kind of hard to work with]. If you know the max possible vector length you might want to hardcode it: `dense_shape=[batch_size, max_vector_length]`